# UDF to generate JSON string behaving inconsistently

Tags: scala, apache-spark, json4s, qubole

I'm trying to generate a JSON string to store a variable number of history records in a single STRING column.  The code works on all of my small tests, but fails (no error, just no data) when run on the actual data. Here's what I have:

```
class HistoryDetail (
  var date : String,
  var val1 : Int,
  var val2 : Int,
  var changeCode : String
)

class HistoryHeader(
  var numDetailRecords : Int,
  var calcDate : String,
  var historyRecords : List[HistoryDetail]
)

def getJSON = (val1:Int, val2:Int) => {
  implicit val formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats;
  val today = LocalDate.now
  val hdl = List(new HistoryDetail(today.toString, val1, val2, "D"))
  val hh:HistoryHeader = new HistoryHeader(1,today.toString,hdl)
  Serialization.write(hh);
}
```

Very simple test calling the Scala function works fine:

```
val strJson = getJSON(1000,1000)
strJson: String = {"numDetailRecords":1,"calcDate":"2018-04-23","historyRecords":[{"date":"2018-04-23","val1":1000,"val2":1000,"changeCode":"D"}]}
```

Creating the UDF and applying to a small DataFrame works fine:

```
spark.udf.register("getJSONUDF", getJSON)
val smallDF = Seq((100, 100), (101, 101), (102, 102)).toDF("int_col1", "int_col2").withColumn("json_col",callUDF("getJSONUDF", $"int_col1", $"int_col2"))
smallDF.show(false)

+--------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|int_col1|int_col2|json_col                                                                                                                      |
+--------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|100     |100     |{"numDetailRecords":1,"calcDate":"2018-04-23","historyRecords":[{"date":"2018-04-23","val1":100,"val2":100,"changeCode":"D"}]}|
|101     |101     |{"numDetailRecords":1,"calcDate":"2018-04-23","historyRecords":[{"date":"2018-04-23","val1":101,"val2":101,"changeCode":"D"}]}|
|102     |102     |{"numDetailRecords":1,"calcDate":"2018-04-23","historyRecords":[{"date":"2018-04-23","val1":102,"val2":102,"changeCode":"D"}]}|
+--------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Running it against the actual data fails (again no error, just no data):

```
val bigDF = spark.read.table("table_name")
                      .select($"int_col1",$"int_col2")
                      .withColumn("json_col",callUDF("getJSONUDF", $"int_col1", $"int_col2"))
bigDF.show(false)
+--------+--------+--------+
|int_col1|int_col2|json_col|
+--------+--------+--------+
|18995   |12702   |{}      |
|14989   |46998   |{}      |
|25588   |25051   |{}      |
|18750   |52282   |{}      |
|19963   |25745   |{}      |
|17500   |21587   |{}      |
|21999   |20379   |{}      |
|25975   |5988    |{}      |
|26382   |5988    |{}      |
|7049    |101907  |{}      |
|45997   |47472   |{}      |
|45997   |47472   |{}      |
|13950   |158957  |{}      |
|18999   |123689  |{}      |
|33842   |69623   |{}      |
|64000   |13362   |{}      |
|64000   |13362   |{}      |
|64000   |13362   |{}      |
|64000   |13362   |{}      |
|64000   |13362   |{}      |
+--------+--------+--------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

(Versions: java 1.8.0_60, spark 2.2.0, scala 2.11.8)

Any thoughts on why I am getting an empty JSON object when using the larger DataFrame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TBH I don't know what exactly goes wrong because I would have expected a `Task not serializable` error at some point. My best guess would be that the `getJSON` is not thread safe and keeps a centralized state somewhere of the to be encoded object. Again this may be completely wrong

I think your approach could be better though, by using the `to_json` function from Spark.

```
def getHistoryReader = udf((val1:Int, val2:Int) => {
  val today = LocalDate.now
  val hdl = List(new HistoryDetail(today.toString, val1, val2, "D"))
  new HistoryHeader(1,today.toString,hdl)
})

val bigDF = spark.read.table("table_name")
  .select($"int_col1",$"int_col2")
  .withColumn("json_col",to_json(getHistoryReader($"int_col1", $"int_col2")))

bigDF.show(false)
```

Looks cleaner in my opinion and leaves the json serialization to Spark.
This should work

Comment: Thanks! That got me 99% of the way there.  At first, I got `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type HistoryHeader is not supported`.  I converted the classes for `case class` and dropped the `new` statements, and then it worked.  It never occurred to me that Scala class would work like a StructType.